# How can I divide 2 namens and convert them to a E-Mail Adress with lixtboxes? (Visual Baisc 2010)

Tags: for-loop, listbox

How to make a programm that reads in 2 buttons that have different stages of Leeting (in Visual Basic 2010):
Stage 1: Converts a Name (William Afton as an example) to William_Afton@abc.com (not a real E-Mail adress btw)

Stage 2: Converts William Afton to w.afton@abc.com

However for some reason I can't really programm stage 2. It always ends up with errors.

Here is my current script for the Stage 2 Button:

Can anyone find out what I did wrong?

So I programmed Stage 2 Button with this script:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
ListBox2.Items.Add((ListBox1.Items.Item(i).First.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("Ü", "UE").Replace("Ö", "OE").Replace("Ä", "AE").Replace("ü", "ue").Replace("ö", "ue").Replace("ä", "ae") & "." & "@fbs.com"))
Next
```

I was expecting to get results like "w.afton@abc.com " but instead the programm stopped working and showed me a yellow marked line instead, which implies that I made some error.